# Java installation failed

Tags: installation, java

I am trying to install Java jdk 10 in my computer but it won't install. It is giving me an error saying:

[image]

But, I can't find the Java installation that is running in the back end. I have tried to search online, but no success.  Please help me with the situation.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to install Java JDK 10 in my computer but it won't install. It is giving me an error saying:
>
> [image]

Java generates a lock file, this prevents the installer from being started twice, if the installer is interrupted and the lock is not removed it would explain the behavior you have encountered.

The lock file is located within `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\JAVA_INSTALL_FLAG`.  My suggested solution is to just remove the Java folder entirely.  **This lock file location only applies to JDK 10.**